# Pandas series: how to compute daily cumulative sum of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a pandas dataframe where each index is represented as a datetime object in the form like `2009-01-30 23:01:45` .

In order to calculate the total value of a column in each day, I've used the following workarounds:

```
df['col1'].resample('D').sum().cumsum()
```

or

```
df.groupby(df.index.date)['col1'].sum().cumsum()
```

where both can return my desired output.

However I was wondering is there another solution without using two successive aggregation functions, `.sum().cumsum()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Both sum() and cumsum() will do different operations.
sum() with groupby will add all the Values in the Val column for each date.
whereas cumsum() - cumulative sum will add the first date(row) sum result with the second date(row) sum result and populate in the second row and add this value with the third date(row) sum result and it continues.

So it is based in the requirement whether you need just sum of values for each date or you need cumulative sum as well. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  But I seek another solution to replace such operations.

Comment: I think both are different operations so you can't replace both as one.